# Vim: How to yank a visual block to a register?

Tags: vim

I can yank a line to register `a` by `"ayy`.

But I am not able to figure out a way to yank some visually selected block to a particular register. If I just press `y` after selection, it stores it in the default register. But I need to store it in a specific register, how can this be achieved?

Answer (score 50, accepted):

It's the same behaviour, but you tell the register after the visual selection.

An example:

You select some text in visual mode and copy it to register `a`:

```
V4j"ay
```

Go to end of file:

```
G
```

And paste it:

```
"ap
```

Comment: That worked. I tried many combinations, but some how missed this one. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 14):

I can select a block using `shift+v` or `vap` (read: "visually select around paragraph") and then yank it using `"ay`. When I want to paste it again I use `"ap` or `"aP`.

Does this work for you?

Comment: It worked. Thanks. It is sad that i could only accept one answer.

Comment: just note that `shift-V` and `vap` are line/char-wise selection. `Ctrl-V` enter block-wise selection mode.

Answer (score 5):

under

```
:help yank
```

you'll find

```
{Visual}["x]y           Yank the highlighted text [into register x] (for
                        {Visual} see |Visual-mode|).  {not in Vi}


{Visual}["x]Y           Yank the highlighted lines [into register x] (for
                        {Visual} see |Visual-mode|).  {not in Vi}
```

So, select something visually then use `"` *registername* `y`.